# asp.net WCF heavy traffic site breaks databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, data-binding

I am having an issue with an internal site during testing ( 50 + users).

the pages work fine with 1 or 2 users but when a bunch of peoples hit the site, I get errors for a lot of my data bindings "**System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name** ".

all these property names exist in the results I return from the database. but for some reason it happens with a lot of users at the same time.

I am using asp.net 4.0 and WCF.

The pages use data repeaters to bind data. i aslo checked the database and the responses from the database server are good, no issues there, so its purely application problem.
any help is much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you forget to close the database ? and fail to open it again ?

Comment: Few things: 1) please include a FULL stck trace. 2) Please provide some sample code you're using for databinding. 3) Please provide your WCF service binding definition.

Answer (score 1):

It seem there is a performance issue.
You can:
 1.Use the simpler data source

   2.Use output caching or partial caching

   3.use data caching in your business logic layer ( like asp.net internal cache or Application Block Cache Helper , ... )

4.Review generated SQL by ORM(Entity Framework) and optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a really basic databinder, like SQLDataReader.  It seems to me that you have some resource issues.  And ensure you close all your connection strings.